# How to simulate LAST() in mysql on datetime field

Tags: mysql

I want to get a list of customers who had not ordered in the last 15 days.

I am using `query`

```
SELECT u.name, u.primary_phone 
FROM orders o 
    INNER JOIN user u ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE DATE(o.created_at) <= 'date set to 15 days back';
```

I want to use `LAST(o.created_at)` but `mysql` doesn't permits it

Comment: Care to post some easy to check data and results? see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It will help us to know when we are providing useful answrs.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.... will take care hence forth

Answer (score 0):

To substract 15 days from the current date you can do

```
SELECT u.name ,u.primary_phone 
from orders o 
inner join user u on o.user_id = u.id 
where DATE(o.created_at) <= curdate() - interval 15 day
```

If you want to get only users not having ordered in the last 5 days do

```
SELECT u.name, u.primary_phone 
from user u 
left join orders o on o.user_id = u.id 
group by u.name, u.primary_phone 
having sum(DATE(o.created_at) >= curdate() - interval 15 day) = 0
```

Comment: This will select all customers that ordered something 15 days ago or before. Even those who ordered yesterday.

Comment: No, it will not. It selects only orders at least 15 days old.

Comment: Yes, but OP wants to get a list of customers who haven't ordered for last 15 days. Not orders older than 15 days.